# check service status on ubuntu server by windows-service on windows server

Tags: c#, shell, ubuntu, command-line, windows-server

i have a huge problem with my Windows-Service (C#). We had a system change on a few servers (from windows 2012R2 to Ubuntu) and for all these servers i wrote a monitoring tool as windows service running on a windows server. In this service i checked a few things on the server which worked fine. One of the things i had to check was if some special windows services (e.g. iis) are in `state = running`.

So - is there ANY possibility to check an Ubuntu-Service programmatically from my monitoring service? Can i set commands on the Ubuntu shell? Or start a bat File?

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("servicename", "ubuntu-IP"))
```

Using a ServiceController doesn't work i guess because of Windows != Ubuntu?!

It should be an "easy" way to do it - so if it would be too ornate i just don't do it.

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: totally rewrote, I misunderstood the question.

Linux does not use services the way Windows does, first of all there is no infrastructure to remotely check and manage the services like in a windows domain.

You have two options there:

1-Connect through SSH with an account with admin privileges and issue "service (servicename) status", this wil yield if the service is running or not. To connect through SSH the servers must have an SSH server configured and use some C# library for the SSH connection (per example this: https://sshnet.codeplex.com/)

2-Create a C# service and use Mono on your servers, in this way that service can execute commands locally like "ps" or use Process.GetProcesses(), then you can comunicate this process with your Windows process the way you best like, per example TCP or UDP.

Comment: no mono! i thought mono is a c# tool for linux/ubuntu services? my monitoring service is running on the windows server.

Comment: Wops, then I misunderstood the question, sorry!